# Is my azalea dying?

Tags: diagnosis

[image][image]I bought an azalea at the garden centre and it was being kept outside so I planted it outside and added some shrub food with the compost when I planted it and watered it thoroughly. It has been rainy and quite windy and I can see it has started to lose some leaves and it doesn't look as "perky" anymore. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Just because I can’t see it clearly: is the root ball flush with the soil level? It seems it is sticking out an inch or so?

Comment: Yes, it's sticking out a bit. I added another picture. Should I add more compost to the base?

Comment: I’ll leave it to the community to write a proper answer. Just wanted to help clarify a little detail.